# Custom sorter for two values on same column

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a column in sapui5 table where I am using two values to be displayed in an HBox; "date" and "time". Moreover, in leading property field, I have defined "date" field.

I have a personalization box for this table, where it provides sorting functionality based on "date" field (since "date" is defined in leading property, and one can only have single leading property for a column).

**Date sorting-**> works fine and as expected.

**Issue is,** for same dates, I cannot sort further based on time. So in the picture below, I should get 22:01 first, and then other 22:56 data. This is not happening.

I want to know if there is any way I can implement *more than one* condition in p13n sorting? If yes, how? I tried to find also some CDS annotations which can be used but found none.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Basic JS sort() requires you to write a function that returns a number indicating if one element should come before the other. So the logic to sort on multiples at the same time is just: check first property to sort on, if they're equal, check second property to sort on.

Comment: try to use object identifier instead of HBox, its the standard way of achieving what you try to do with he HBox

Comment: whats your data provider? An OData service? since the sorting happens in the backend i guess you need to look there for the error. without more of your code i cant really tell though, please add the code for the sorter and the table to the question

Comment: @Erch yes, my source is oData service. There is no code for sorter, it is handled by p13n automatically

Comment: how do you sort in backend? the p13n dialog just writes sorters in the binding of your table, so if it doesnt sort properly, its about your backend implementation, please share how you sort in the backend. (Either your cds view or your *_get_entityset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Actually, SAP backend has two date formats for 12'o clock; 00:00 & 24:00.

Ideally, 00:00 means 12'o clock at the start of the day & 24:00 means 12'o clock at the end of the day.

However, SAPUI5 right now does not support 24:00 in sorting. (You can also not select 24:00 as time in date picker, the max you can select is 23:59).

[image]

Hence, sorting in my case was correct, how ever it was seeming wrong because 24:00 is converted to 00:00 by UI5.

There is no direct solution provided by UI5. What I did was to reformat the time to 24:00 in formatter.js.